# Kotlin SAM interface and method reference

Tags: kotlin

I am a bit confused why I can do the following

```
val outputter1: (s: String) -> Unit = ::println
```

but when I do

```
val outputter2: Outputter = ::println
```

given

```
fun interface Outputter {
    fun output(output: String)
}
```

I get a compilation error

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
println() defined in kotlin.io
println(Any?) defined in kotlin.io
...
```

Shouldn't method references translate to SAM inteface types as well as Function types?

Comment: Functional interface conversion is available since Kotlin 1.4. What Kotlin version are you using?

Comment: The OP's behaviour is reproducible even in 1.6.10: https://pl.kotl.in/RWSTp2mgn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, SAM conversions must be explicit in assignments (despite the type declaration) using the auto-generated adapter functions:

```kotlin
val outputter2: Outputter = Outputter { println(it) } // OK
val outputter3: Outputter = Outputter(::println) // OK

val outputter4: Outputter = { s: String -> println(s) } // compile error
```

But they are inferred fine in function calls:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    takesOutputter(::println) // OK
}

fun takesOutputter(o: Outputter) {
    o.output("test")
}
```

For reference, checkout the [doc on Kotlin SAM conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html#sam-conversions), and [this part](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) in the Java interop section which gives more examples of SAM conversions.

Comment: I have a theory on this restriction. When you're passing a function to a higher-order function, there's low risk of a problem occurring from the passed function getting wrapped to meet the arg. type because it's passing through a function boundary. If they allowed this automatic wrapping when assigning properties/variables, you would get weird situations where two variables that supposedly are pointing at the same object are not. For example: `val a: (String)->Unit = ::println; val b: Outputter = a; assert(a === b)`. If the compiler allowed this, the assertion would fail, which is surprising.

Comment: @Tenfour04 That's a fair point, although technically this could apply to function calls too: if your example of `a` is a property in a class, and you pass it to the method `fun test(b: Outputter)` in that same class, asserting `a === b` inside the `test` function would fail just as much. I could very much see it happening with `fun unregister(listener: Listener)` - should 2 `Listener` instances wrapping the same function be considered equal?

Comment: Yes, it's still possible. I'm just speculating at the design decision. I've actually encountered the problem you're discussing before. Listeners don't have useful equals methods, so registering/unregistering listeners breaks down when SAM-wrapped functional references are involved.

Comment: Is `Outputter(::println)` here acting as some kind of constructor that takes a function as parameter? Anywhere in the docs where this is covered or where I can find a SAM interface being invoked like this `Outputter()` in the docs?

Comment: @AlexT Yes, it's technically just a conveniently named function, but it acts exactly like a constructor, and it does take a function as argument (and you can pass lambdas and method refs, as shown in my answer). The doc I linked in the answer (the one about Java interop) mentions them: *an adapter function that converts a lambda to a specific SAM type. Those adapter functions are also generated by the compiler when needed*. I don't know if there are other references of that, though